# Can't compile LaTeX document when glossaries package is used (fatal error)

Tags: miktex, glossaries

I just followed the instructions for setting up TeXnicCenter to work with the glossaries package as described at [latex-community.org](http://www.latex-community.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=263&catid=55). I am trying to create a list of acronyms, however, I will not be using them in text. My document looks like this:

```
\documentclass[bibtotoc,liststotoc,BCOR5mm,DIV12]{scrbook}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{bold-extra}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\graphicspath{{./Bilder/}}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{lvm}{LVM}{Logical Volume Manager}

\input{hyphenation}

\begin{document}

% ---------------------------------------------------------------

\frontmatter
\include{./Titel/titel-lmu}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage
\tableofcontents

% ---------------------------------------------------------------
\mainmatter
\input{chapter1}

% ---------------------------------------------------------------
\backmatter
\printglossaries
\listoftables
\listoffigures
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{./Bib/stud77}
\end{document}
```

When I try to compile, I get the following error.

```
)
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 126.
<inserted text>
                \fi
l.55   \input{chapter2}


The file ended while I was skipping conditional text.
This kind of error happens when you say `\if...' and forget
the matching `\fi'. I've inserted a `\fi'; this might work.

)
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 126.
<inserted text>
                \fi
<*> ...itung/stud77/Dokumentation/Latex/stud77.tex

The file ended while I was skipping conditional text.
This kind of error happens when you say `\if...' and forget
the matching `\fi'. I've inserted a `\fi'; this might work.

! Emergency stop.
<*> ...itung/stud77/Dokumentation/Latex/stud77.tex

*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)
```

I actually get this error as soon as I add `\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}` line to my document before anything else has been set up, too. I'm using MiKTeX 2.9. Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: Commenting the 3 `include` lines in your example and the bibliography,  I can't reproduce your problem. It seems like it happens at the `include` of a `chapter2` that we can't see in your example, and related rather to a malformed `if` than to a `glossary`.

Comment: @huitseeker Don’t comment – this will only cause cross-posts. Instead, flag the post so it can be moved.

Comment: There is indeed 6 chapters that are included there. However, I'm not using \iffalse anywhere in the document, so I assume it must be something with the glossaries as everything compiles just fine before \usepackage[glossaries] is added...

Comment: @Lex Well maybe you are doing something in your code (a package, a command) that uses this if-statement. So go ahead and do the usual error search. Comment out everything until the error disappears, then bring parts in again (step by step) and see where the error shows. Delete temporary files as well. Also I think you should load hyperrey at a later point, just before glossaries. the url package is not needed if you load hyperref

Comment: @Lex: Since there's no further information, this question has been closed. Feel free to add information, then we could reopen it.